# Wireless n/w is not showing up in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Wireless n/w is not showing up in ubuntu 14.04 after formating my pc, However I am able to connect internet via LAN.
Please find below link contains wireless-info.txt file information

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16198709/

sudo iwconfig

display below results

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: We see no wireless device at all in your paste. Is it an internal device or a USB? Is there an option to enable and disable the device in the BIOS? Is it possible that the device is broken?

Comment: Hi,thanks for prompt response, I installed ubuntu 14.04 using bootable pen drive. I didn't find any option in BIOS for enable and disable the device either. Can i install ubuntu 16.04 to soirt out this issue. Does it make any sense ?

Comment: I doubt that Installing a different Ubuntu version will suddenly discover a device that is not discoverable by 14.04 but it is easy enough to try the live DVD or USB session and find out. Start it up and run: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and `lsusb`. Did you see any wireless device that wasn't present in your paste above?

Comment: I've Installed  16.04 but doesn't resolve my problem. after running lspci -nn | grep 0280 command doesnt return any output. however lsusb return some device information. Please have a look below url:-  

http://postimg.org/image/3w8obuych/

Thanks

Comment: We see a card reader, a webcam (integrated, but attached to a USB bus internally), an optical mouse, and a USB hub, but no wireless. Sorry.

Comment: hmm, is there any way left to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Buy a fully supported USB wireless or else replace the internal, perhaps PCIe, wireless. That's all I know of.