# Wireless Network not showing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I cannot connect to my wireless network. I have referred many stack overflow questions related to this and the one that I found closest, perhaps the exact was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766704/wireless-n-w-is-not-showing-up-in-ubuntu-14-04), the difference only being that problem started after I suspended my pc and then woke it up. I tried rebooting my pc, followed some steps in other Stack Overflow answers, but the problem still persists. It fails to show `wlan0`. However, I am able to connect to my network via ethernet. I have a Dell 5558 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. Reading the comments in the above referenced link, is it an internal problem or can I rectify it using software? I can post any information if required. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 There was no output shown.

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 No. I am using a wireless router

Comment: I mean do you use an external USB dongle with your laptop?

Comment: Sorry , but no, I do not use an external USB dongle

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` then.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17171624/

Comment: It looks like there is no wireless adapter, or it is disabled it bios, or it is broken. Try to reset bios to defaults.

Comment: And what does `lsusb` show?

Comment: Thank you! Thanks a lot! Resetting the bios did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is not shown in `lspci`. It is probably disabled in BIOS.

Resetting BIOS to default may solve the problem.

Comment: [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17173290/) is the output of `lspci` after I had reset the bios, if any one is interested.