# Cannot boot Ubuntu 14.04 ; /init: line 11: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

I had once again ran into the issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785313/wireless-network-not-showing-ubuntu-14-04). After I had reset the bios, Ubuntu fails to boot. Shows the error `/init: line 11: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found`. My boot option is set to `UEFI` boot option as before. I have tried enabling and disabling `secure boot` but there was no luck. The first boot sequence is UBUNTU (boot option name) and it points to the file name `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi`. 
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `/dev/sr0` should be your CD/DVD drive. No idea why you get that error though.

Comment: Any idea on how to debug it? It shows me a shell prompt after all those errors.

Comment: Check your `/etc/fstab` file to see if there's a reference to `/dev/sr0`. If you find such a reference, you may need to comment it out. *NOTE:* If you're booting *from* an optical disc, or if your boot legitimately relies on an optical disc being present, you must present details for any hope of proper diagnosis.

Comment: @RodSmith I didn't find any references to `/dev/sr0`. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22340943/) is my  `/etc/fstab` file. Ubuntu was perfectly working fine for me and it was pre installed.  I do not want it to boot from an optical disc, rather I want it to boot from the file system, as before. Right now, I am commenting from a live version of Ubuntu 14.04 via usb on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks guys! [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) did some magic for me and Ubuntu boots fine. Should I consider deleting this question? Or maybe you guys can delete it if it isn't a useful question.